# Any existing javascript library to change svg fill color? animated preferable

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

googled but cant be found ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://keith-wood.name/svg.html#anim

Answer (score 1):

Raphael http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/raphael-a-javascript-api-for-svg/

Answer (score 0):

add the jquery.color plugin, then add to your code:

```
  jQuery.Color.hook( "fill stroke" );
```

then the animate function is what you would expect

```
    $('g').animate({
        'fill': '#07F',
    }, {
        duration: 1150,
        queue: false,
        complete: function() {}
    })
```